# Keyboard shortcut to wake from sleep?

Tags: macos, mac

I currently have the new MacBook Pro connected to a external monitor, USB keyboard, and a USB mouse. I set it to sleep every night but it wakes up with the slightest touch/activity on the mouse or keyboard. I also own two cats who walk all over my table, thus waking my MacBook Pro in the middle of the night from sleep. Is there a way I can set a keyboard shortcut to wake my MacBook Pro from sleep rather than any keystroke doing so?

Comment: Why are you concerned about it waking up?

Comment: Unplug the external  keyboard, mouse and close the lid of the MacBook Pro.

Comment: there is a solution similar to this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13600/71498 .. but I need to figure out how to work with the new log system. I will probably write an Answer to this soon..!